# Custom listview cell

Tags: android, listview

When the button is clicked is should show the picture! Can you help me?

[image: Click here see picture]

Comment: what are you trying to say, be more clear and specific

Comment: Please clearly specify what you want to say

Comment: Please provide some code what you are trying.

Comment: I want to do same picture. When click button, will push cell listview turn left, show two button in turn righ.

Comment: Please add what you have tried?

Comment: If you want on button click expand any listview or something else, you can use ExpandableListView or ExpandableLayout.